# Android app screen size does not fit device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, crash

i'm new to developing so i don't know if i'm doing it right
i just downloaded an app from market and it doesn't fit my screen (ldpi 240x320) on height... some buttons on the bottom don't appear.
so i googled some info and tried everything...
here is layout/Main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.launcher">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/LLImage" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:minHeight="100.0dip"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.launcher">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@id/drag_layer" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="370.0dip" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:minHeight="100.0dip">
            <ImageView android:id="@id/imageViewContainer" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="370.0dip" android:src="@drawable/backgsammi" android:scaleType="matrix" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:minHeight="100.0dip" />
            <ImageView android:id="@id/imageWatermark" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/watermark" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/mainLLauout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.launcher">
        <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@drawable/background" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50.0dip"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <ImageButton android:padding="0.0px" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="3.0dip" android:src="@drawable/open" android:text="Select Picture" android:onClick="openGallery" />
            <ImageButton android:padding="0.0px" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="3.0dip" android:src="@drawable/cat" android:text="Choose Cat" android:onClick="chooseCat" />
            <ImageButton android:id="@id/btnFlip" android:padding="0.0px" android:longClickable="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="3.0dip" android:src="@drawable/rotate" android:onClick="rotateImage" />
            <ImageButton android:padding="0.0px" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="3.0dip" android:src="@drawable/eraser" android:onClick="eraseImage" />
            <ImageButton android:id="@id/btnSave" android:padding="0.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="3.0dip" android:src="@drawable/save" android:text="Save" android:onClick="saveToGallery" />
            <ImageButton android:padding="0.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="3.0dip" android:src="@drawable/help" android:text="Save" android:onClick="openHelp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i guess it's because of "android:layout_height="370.0dip"" - it should be smaller. but when i try to change it to "360" or "fill_parent" on eclipse, sign apk, install on phone and try to open the app, it crashes. am I missing something? i'm just trying to make app fit my phone screen

sorry for bad english and that stupid question

```
    05-16 18:21:30.796: W/dalvikvm(11715): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.addacat.addacat/com.addacat.addacat.AddaCatActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.addacat.addacat.AddaCatActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.addacat.addacat-2.apk]
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.addacat.addacat.AddaCatActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.addacat.addacat-2.apk]
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
05-16 18:21:31.306: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    ... 11 more
```

a

```
package com.addacat.addacat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AddaCatActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

that's everything is on AddaCatActivity.java

Comment: You can use emulator for testing your app. No need to sign it every time and install on phone.

Comment: you should enable debugging an install from misc. sources on your phone's settings, and then run / debug the application directly on phone. Watch the logcat output, it will surely have details about the source of the problem you are dealing with.

Comment: thanks... it helps a lot, but there's some errors and i don't know how to fix them... lol... i was just trying to change the screen size

Answer (score 0):

I tested your layout in a dummy app using 20px x 20px images in place of your your images.  It does not crash when I change those heights from 370dip to fill_parent.

You really need to get the app running on either the emulator or off your phone while it's connected to Eclipse.  You need to be able to see the LogCat.  It will likely give you a good idea of what the cause may be.

---

Edits:

Now that you've fixed the app crashing issue, you should take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) page.  It gives a number of examples of how to build a layout.

Right now, you've got:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout>  // Unused
    <RelativeLayout>
      <ImageView />
      <ImageView />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout>  // Unused
    <LinearLayout>
      <ImageButton />
      <ImageButton />
      <ImageButton />
      <ImageButton />
      <ImageButton />
      <ImageButton />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

At this point, at least two of your LinearLayout blocks look to be unused.  Here's a layout that does what I think you were going for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/drag_layer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:minHeight="100.0dip" >

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageViewContainer"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/backgsammi"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageWatermark"
      android:visibility="invisible"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/watermark"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

  </RelativeLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/mainLLauout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0" >

    <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:src="@drawable/open" />

    <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:src="@drawable/cat" />

    <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:src="@drawable/rotate" />

    <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:src="@drawable/eraser" />

    <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:src="@drawable/save" />

    <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:src="@drawable/help" />

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it seems there's something wrong with app name: com.addacat.addacat/com.addacat.addacat.AddaCatActivity

Comment: That's what it looks like, but I don't know why that would show up only if you change 370dip to fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

**about pixels sizes:**
1dp equals 1px only on mdpi.
on ldpi , 1dp=(1+1/3)px .
that's because : mdpi is 160dpi , and ldpi is 120dpi.

this means that if your screen is 240x320 and you use dimentions of dp inside "layout" folder (which is intended for mdpi if not specifically written) , 370dp ~493 pixels . that's more than your screen width or height .

read this for more info:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

**about the error itself:**,it seems that the app can't find the activity you wish to start, maybe because you renamed it or you've put it on a different location .

you need to make sure your activity is on the manifest with the correct path. to be perfectly sure the path is ok , put the full path to the activity on the manifest instead of starting with "." and then the name of the activity . for example:

```
<activity android:name="com.my_awesome_app.MyAwesomeActivity" ...
```

Comment: well the app is not crashing anymore and there's no errors on Eclipse but it's just a black screen with nothing on it

Comment: that's a good step. now check if there is a call to "setContentView" inside the "onCreate" method of the activity . if not, please call it and set the paremeter to the layout you've chosen (R.layout.main) , or to something else that you wish to use. also , don't forget that all resources files (inside "res/..." ) should be lowercase , so your "Main.xml" file should be renamed to "main.xml"

Comment: well i can see that you didn't call setContentView as i've written that you should , so currently it shows a blank screen since it doesn't know what to show. please call setContentView(R.layout.main); after the "super.onCreate..." line. this will surely fix everything . since this question is quite basic , please read some tutorials or watch them. i suggest "the new boston" : http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6

Comment: the main screen is ok but when i click on the buttons the app crashes... do i have to fix everything? i just wanted to change screen size

Comment: i don't understand . what is exactly "change screen size" . there are no devices currently that i know of that can change their screen sizes . please explain and show the code that is supposed to do what you want to do.